# React-Native : Need Help Accessing Android Bundled Images with React-Native-Fetch-Blob

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-fetch-blob

I have a folder of Images in my project

I'm struggling to access an image like this
ProjectRoot/App/Images/image.png

in iOS I can access it by using:

```
RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.MainBundleDir + 'assets/App/Images/image.png'
```

What would be the Android way? I've tried `DocumentDir` and `MainBundleDir`, I've only had a "file doesn't exist" returned

I have tried `RNFetchBlob.fs.asset('image.png')` and `RNFetchBlob.fs.asset('path/to/image.png')` and haven't been successful

I've logged out all the files and directories that I have access to and unfortunately I cannot find it

Need some help.

It is suggested that you can add

aaptOptions, noCompress to prevent assets in the Android assets folder from compressing into the bundle, however they exit outside of the Android project folder structure

"react-native": "0.49.1",
"react-native-fetch-blob": "0.10.8",

Android:
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
targetSdkVersion 23

Answer (score 1):

I solved it in my instance.

Basically, and unfortunately, you need to duplicate the assets into your Android asset folder

e.g.

```
ProjectRoot/App/Images/image.jpg
```

must be copied to

`ProjectRoot/android/app/src/main/assets/image.jpg`

(subfolders can be used if needed)

rerun your packager and then the files are accessible by

```
RNFetchBlob.fs.asset("image.jpg")
```

Comment: Can you substitute the PATH string required by e.g. `copyFile` or `appendFile` with that? Or do you need to use `RNFetchBlob.wrap(RNFetchBlob.fs.asset('my-asset.png')))`? Or how does that work?